# How to merge two dataframes with all same columns and create new columns with old columns as rows in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes a and b like following

[Dataframe a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy9pv.jpg)

[Dataframe b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID131.jpg)

And I want to combine these two dataframe somehow to create another dataframe which looks something like

[Dataframe c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFHrp.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
df_c = pd.concat([df_a, df_b]).sort_values(by=['a']).rename(columns= {'a': 'alpha', 'b': 'value1', 'c': 'value2'})
```

Comment: How can we do it if we had more columns(maybe 30) in both dataframes, and we still want to bring them down to two?

Comment: The desired dataframe you posted has three columns. Checkout the pandas documentation (merge and concat).